# TortoiseGIT and sftp

Tags: git, sftp, tortoise-git

I have a server which I can't modify/install anything on that.
the only way that server gives me is to use sftp protocol to connect to the server and modify the files. I have access to the server using a key and a user name. these are tested and are working when I use the FileZilla client.
Now I want to push to my server using tortoiseGIT or command line, but I can't find any option for using the sftp protocol on tortoiseGit. is it at all possible?

Comment: Please more details. What kind of server? Windows, Unix, Linux, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Set the remote URL in TortoiseGit as follows:

```
ssh://<username>@<server-address>/<repository-folder>
```

Of course replace `<username>`, `<server-address>` and `<repository-folder>` with their corresponding values.

Comment: what does it has to do with what he asked?

Comment: @vsync - The OP wanted to use TortoiseGIT to push to a server to which he has sftp access. Setting the remote URL in TortoiseGit like I suggested allows him to do exactly that.

Comment: ho, now I understand what he wanted.. I thought it was something I am after. maybe you would know.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28750666/104380